# Error when making a migration on doctrine

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying to create a table into a sql server by making a migration for the entity I just created, but it throws an exception when executing the query:

```
SQLSTATE [42000, 15135]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Object is invalid. Extended properties are not permitted on 'dbo.[user].roles', or the object does not exist.
```

By using maker-bundle I created a new User entity

I made the migration:

$ php bin/console make:migration

```
  Success!


 Next: Review the new migration "src/Migrations/Version20181121121145.php"
 Then: Run the migration with php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
 See https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html
```

Then when migrating the migration:

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate

                    Application Migrations


WARNING! You are about to execute a database migration that could result in schema changes and data loss. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n)y
Migrating up to 20181121121145 from 0

  ++ migrating 20181121121145

     -> CREATE TABLE [user] (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, username NVARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, password NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))
     -> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677 ON [user] (username) WHERE username IS NOT NULL
     -> EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'(DC2Type:json)', N'SCHEMA', 'dbo', N'TABLE', '[user]', N'COLUMN', roles
Migration 20181121121145 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred while executing 'EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'(DC2Type:json)', N'SCHEMA', 'dbo', N'TABLE', '[user]', N'COLUMN', roles':

SQLSTATE [42000, 15135]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Object is invalid. Extended properties are not permitted on 'dbo.[user].roles', or the object does not exist.

In DBALException.php line 187:

  An exception occurred while executing 'EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'(DC2Type:json)', N'SCHEMA', '
  dbo', N'TABLE', '[user]', N'COLUMN', roles':

  SQLSTATE [42000, 15135]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Object is invalid. Extended properties
   are not permitted on 'dbo.[user].roles', or the object does not exist.


In SQLSrvException.php line 57:

  SQLSTATE [42000, 15135]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Object is invalid. Extended properties
   are not permitted on 'dbo.[user].roles', or the object does not exist.


doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql [WRITE-SQL]] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]] [--db DB] [--em EM] [--shard SHARD] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> [<version>]
```

The migration file looks as follow:

```
//Version20181121121145.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20181121121145 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mssql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mssql\'.');

        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE [user] (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, username NVARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, password NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649F85E0677 ON [user] (username) WHERE username IS NOT NULL');
        $this->addSql('EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N\'MS_Description\', N\'(DC2Type:json)\', N\'SCHEMA\', \'dbo\', N\'TABLE\', \'[user]\', N\'COLUMN\', roles');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mssql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mssql\'.');

        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_accessadmin');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_backupoperator');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_datareader');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_datawriter');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_ddladmin');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_denydatareader');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_denydatawriter');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_owner');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA db_securityadmin');
        $this->addSql('CREATE SCHEMA dbo');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE [user]');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**First Solution:**

I opened SQL Server Management Studio and tested one by one the three queries. The first two worked just find but the third one failed, so I did what @sepupic said and it worked.

Can somebody explain me why when I made the migration using the maker-bundle, the query below:

```
$this->addSql('EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N\'MS_Description\', N\'(DC2Type:json)\', N\'SCHEMA\', \'dbo\', N\'TABLE\', \'[user]\', N\'COLUMN\', roles');
```

din't show **user** instead of **[user]**?

**Final Solution**
It seems to be 'user' is a reserved word, so I refactored the class to a different name and it worked just fine from the beginning to the end

Comment: >>>Can somebody explain me why when I made the migration using the maker-bundle, the query below: din't show user instead of [user]?<<< My guess is that the migration tool thinks that **user** is a keyword ad put it in brackets

Comment: Now when I try to insert data into the table it throws:     An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (username, roles, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["felipito", "[]", "canelo123", "fpcanelo@ati.cu"]:

SQLSTATE [42000, 156]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
SQLSTATE [42000, 8180]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. Maybe the solution given has something to do with that? @sepupic

Comment: And for INSERT it's mandatory to include table name within brackets as it is keyword: INSERT INTO dbo.[user] ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that 'user' is a reserved word in sql server, so I refactored the class to a different name and it worked just fine from the beginning to the end

Answer (score 2):

Your code should look like this:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'(DC2Type:json)', N'SCHEMA', 'dbo', N'TABLE', 'user', N'COLUMN', 'roles'
```

The error told you that the object 'dbo.**[user]**.roles' does not exist and in fact your object is 'dbo.**user**.roles' without brackets, so you should use `'user'` as parameter for your table, not `'[user]'`

Comment: I did what I explained at the bottom of the question and it worked. Thanks @sepupic

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this issue is caused by "user" being a reserved keyword in SQL Server. It's worth pointing out that Doctrine provides the `table` attribute which allows you to specify the table name for the entity to get around this. This is simpler than having to refactor/rename your `User` entity, `UserRepository`, update *security.yaml*, etc.

### PHP 8.0+

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'app_user')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface {...}
```

Note that it's `'app_user'` and not `` '`app_user`' ``. The latter results in the table name being referred to as `[app_user]` as mentioned in sepupic's answer.

### Prior to PHP 8.0

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @Table(name="app_user")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface {...}
```