# Error inserting data into a table using doctrine and mssql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to insert data into a created database with the corresponding table this way (Symfony4):

```
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/user/new", name="admin_add_new_user")
     */
    public function new_user(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername('felipito')
            ->setPassword('canelo123')
            ->setEmail('fpcanelo@ati.cu');

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'AdminController',
            'brand' => 'brand',
            'msg' => sprintf(
                'New user dude: id #%d user %s', $user->getId(), $user->getUsername()
            )
        ]);
    }
```

Once I open the url it throws the following:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (username, roles, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["felipito", "[]", "canelo123", "fpcanelo@ati.cu"]:

SQLSTATE [42000, 156]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
SQLSTATE [42000, 8180]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Maybe the problem is related with [this problem I had yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401131/error-when-making-a-migration-on-doctrine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like user is a reserved word in MySQL.
Update your User entity @ORM\Table annotation like this.

```
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
  // [....]
}
```

Note the name of the table is using single quotes.

Comment: Hey @rodmar-zavala, besides I'm using sql server, you were right, it seems 'user' is a reserved word in sql server aswell, so I refactored the whole thing again and it worked, thanks

Comment: @Nestor Great! do you mind mark the answer as useful? I am new and trying to gain reputation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like @rodmar-zavala answered, the problem is I was using a reserved word in sql server. It also applies to this error I got when [making the migration on doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401131/error-when-making-a-migration-on-doctrine).

So I refactored the class name and it worked OK.